# Some confusion in using echo

Tags: php, html

I am getting a little confused in using PHP echo statement.
Assume that  i have a basic html layout with the usual tags like `<html><head><body>`  .etc.

Now suppose a echo in the  of the template or maybe outside  , why does the statement get outputted to screen?(because, what i thought is that any text between the head tags is not outputted)

```
<?php
function getName($username)
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alumni WHERE username = '$username'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    echo $row['name'];
}
?>
```

This function is called from the following code

```
<?php session_start();?>
<html>
<?php include("connection.php");?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php");?>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['access']))
{
    $name = getName($_SESSION['username']); 
    echo($name);
}
else
{
    echo("error");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is PHP properly configured and your filename is in the extension `.php` ?

Comment: echo always prints in document. if you want to use something later than define it to variable and echo it to appropriate place.

Comment: Yes, I have named it as test.php

Comment: Are you pasting this PHP code via a CMS or something? Often you can't input PHP that way (CMS will skip not-allowed code entered there) - you need to do so via the actual files.

Comment: @all , i am posting my code, but am facing some problem being new to SO. So sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Acyut click on the [**`Edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22124447/edit) link below your question to update it with your code. Then once you have copy and pasted your code in and removed any sensitive information from it, select all your code and on the visual icons click on code sample its the icon with the 2 brackets `{ }` and it will put your code into code tags for better view of it.

Comment: @all,I have added the code

Comment: `return $row['name'];`

Comment: @Prix, actually, in the original code i have used return, however, for testing purpose i had used echo, and that is the reason of my confusion.

Comment: If your function does not return anything then `$name = getName($_SESSION['username']);` will be null hence why you don't have any data in there. Also you might need to set a global to use the MySQL connection from your function.

Comment: Like i told you, the above code was used by me for testing purpose only. I had removed the cause of error, however just the fact that using an echo within code outside body tag is still reflecting as output on screen is disturbing me, and this is my main question.

Comment: @Acyut your question is making no sense, `echo` prints the output directly to the source code so its only obvious that it will be on the screen and/or source code depending on what you printed. if you have `echo` within included pages or anything else they will show up as the include's or pages are loaded up so you need to properly return things you don't want printed once a function is called to print it when it should be.

Comment: even if it is inside the head tag?

Comment: Yes, even if its on the head tag.

Comment: Ok. thanks :) this was all  i had wanted to know .

Answer (score 0):

HTML isn't like programming languages that are strict about variable scope and keeping things from being displayed/manipulated depending on their placement - you can put text/tags in parts of the page that you'd think would be hidden but they'll possibly be displayed.

If you echo something and don't want it displayed in the browser, use something like this:

```
echo "<!-- DON'T DISPLAY THIS STUFF -->";
```

Remember that PHP is server-side also - if you don't want something displayed at all, don't echo it out -or- use code like this to have PHP ignore the code.

```
/* 
echo "This will be ignored."; 
*/
```